# Built an email adress using Name Surname with awk/sed

Tags: awk, sed, substring

I have name column. I need to built email address using name, for example

```
name            email
Susan Black     sblack@abc.com
maria Kramer    mkramer@abc.com
```

I think to write a regex to remove substring from first position to a space character and add "@abc.com" to end, then using sed do it lowercase. Is this a good idea and how can i realize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `AWK` for this following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
Susan Black
maria Kramer
```

then

```
awk '{print tolower(substr($1,1,1) $2) "@abc.com"}' file.txt
```

output

```
sblack@abc.com
mkramer@abc.com
```

Explanation: get 1-long substring starting at 1st position from 1st column, concat it with 2nd column, make this lowercase then concat with `@abc.com`, `print` such constructed string.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -rn 's/(^[[:alpha:]]{1})(.*[[:space:]])(.*$)/\1\3@abc.com/;s/[[:upper:]]/\L&/gp' file
```

Using sed with regular expression interpretation (-r or -E) split the names into three sections and print the first (first initial) and the third (surname) followed by "@abc.com". We then search for upper case characters and use \L& to convert them to lowercase

Comment: can you advice me some exercises  for practice advanced regex like this?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a great place to see examples and solutions while giving you an opportunity to have a go yourself.

Comment: do you know how realize it with duplicate lines in your code? ex. susan kramer and sean kramer go to skramer@abc.com. I need to do skramer1@abc.com and skramer2@abc.com

Comment: Can you create a new question for that.

Comment: yes, can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65836903/renumbering-duplicate-lines-with-counter-awk