# Renumbering duplicate lines with counter awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have duplicate words in csv. And i need to count it in such way:

```
jsmith
jsmith
kgonzales
shouston
dgenesy
kgonzales
jsmith
```

to this:

```
jsmith@email.com
jsmith1@email.com
kgonzales@email.com
shouston@email.com
dgenesy@email.com
kgonzales1@email.com
jsmith2@email.com
```

I have smth like that, but it doesn't work properly for me..or i cant do it [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29977924/8349144)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your attempts to solve the problem yourself to avoid it getting downvoted for that being missing. Don't post links or images. See [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do it is maintain an array using the username as the index and increment it each time you read a user, e.g.

```
awk '{ print (($1 in a) ? $1 a[$1] : $1) "@email.com"; a[$1]++ }' file
```

The *ternary* `(($1 in a) ? $1 a[$1] : $1)` just checks if the user in in `a[]` yet, and if so uses the name plus the value of the array `$1 a[$1]` if the user is not in the array, then it just uses the user `$1`. The result of the ternary is concatenated with `"@email.com"` to complete the output.

Lastly, the value for the array element for the user is incremented, `a[$1]++`.

**Example Use/Output**

With your names in a file called `users` you would have:

```
$ awk '{ print (($1 in a) ? $1 a[$1] : $1) "@email.com"; a[$1]++ }' users
jsmith@email.com
jsmith1@email.com
kgonzales@email.com
shouston@email.com
dgenesy@email.com
kgonzales1@email.com
jsmith2@email.com
```

---

**To Keep E-mail In Input File**

If your input already contains an e-mail at the end of the username, then you simply want to output that record and skip to the next record, e.g.

```
awk '$1~/@/{print; next} { print (($1 in a) ? $1 a[$1] : $1) "@email.com"; a[$1]++ }' users
```

That will preserve `e.meeks@example.or` from your comment.

**Example Input**

```
jsmith
jsmith
kgonzales
shouston
e.meeks@example.org
dgenesy
kgonzales
jsmith
```

**Example Output**

```
jsmith@email.com
jsmith1@email.com
kgonzales@email.com
shouston@email.com
e.meeks@example.org
dgenesy@email.com
kgonzales1@email.com
jsmith2@email.com
```

Comment: and what if my column already contains a line like this e.meeks@example.org? it goes to  e.meeks@example.org@email.com ( sorry i forgot to mention)

Comment: smthg like if($0 !~ /@/ &&...)

Comment: Oh, this is one where your input is actually different than what you posted in the question? Do you want to remove `@example.org` and change to `@email.com` or do you want to keep `@example.org` ?

Comment: I want to keep it

Comment: Thaanks a lot Sir! Share me how do you learn this hell? From what books or exercises

Comment: @Estet Best place to start is [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents). Take it slow. In `awk` you write rules. Each `{ ... }` is a rule. `awk` will apply the rules to each record (line) of input in the order you write them. Arrays in a`awk` are associative. Meaning you can use strings as indexes. In this answer we just use an array with indexes from your column (e.g. `a[jsmith]`. Each time we see `jsmith` we increase the value at `a[jsmith]` by one (so we know how many times he is seen). Awk is pretty fantastic.

Comment: @Estet if you can have email addresses in your input then edit your question to show email addresses in your input/output. In particular include at least one case where an email address is duplicated in your input so we can see if you also want that duplicated in the output or not. Also include a case where there's a name in your input plus an email address for that name, e.g. `jsmith` and `jsmith@email.com`, to show if you want `jsmith@email.com` to then appear twice in the output or something else.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '{print $0 (arr[$0]++)"@email.com"}' Input_file
```

Simple explanation is printing current line($0) along with an array named arr with index of current line with its increasing count of 1 each time cursor comes here, then printing @email.com which makes output look alike shown output as per OP.